# Painting pressure treated wood and particleboard inside a shed

Tags: paint, shed, pressure-treated

I just had a shed installed that will be used for storing bicycles and scuba diving gear (so sometimes it will be a little damp inside). The walls of the shed are made of smooth planed pressure treated wood. The roof is made of particleboard. I'm in the UK so the temperature range isn't extreme.

I'd like to paint the walls and ceiling inside of the shed white and was wondering if I should use any particular paints. I am concerned that if I use a cheap or incorrect paint that it will either flake off or discolour.

For reference, here's a photo of the inside of the shed.

[image: Shed interior]

### Edit

I've been advised to use [Cuprinol Garden Shades](https://www.cuprinol.co.uk/products/garden_shades.jsp) on the inside and outside, so any thoughts about that will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Cuprinol Garden Shades, White Daisy in the end. I used a combination of roller and brush. Two coats yielded the following result. It went on well, but was very liquid (more so than typical indoor emulsion) so there was quite a lot of splatter (mostly on me).

[image: Shed interior painted with Cuprinol Gardens Shades, White Daisy]

A third coat would have given a better final finish, but for my purposes it's now white (and bright!) enough.

Regarding drying time; I allowed a couple of days between coats. Today (after three more days) the paint is still slightly tacky to the touch in places so it is still not 100% dry. During this time the outside temperature has been between 5°C and 10°C (around 45°F).

Answer (score 2):

Pressure treated wood should be dried out before painting. 3 monthes - a year depending on climate. I would go with a good primer first before painting. Use floor paint for floor or just go with a solid stain.

Answer (score 0):

I've often heard that staining is better than painting for PT wood. They make white, semi-to-very opaque exterior stains. I've used stains such as this for PT fence posts to good effect.

Comment: can you recommend any brands of stain?